# re: applying a patent

Tags: patentability

If a product is already in the market for a specific purpose and is found to be useful in another function by someone else can that person apply for a patent for that new  function?

Answer (score 1):

As a patent is a territorial right you may want to clarify where protection is sought/ which national/ regional legislation should be applied. Your pofile does not state your origin. At this time this may help regarding EU-related matters:

http://www.epo.org/law-practice/legal-texts/html/guidelines/e/f_iv_4_16.htm

The question cannot be answered definitely but one way to get protection may be a use claim. Consult a lawyer of your choice and provide him with details.

Answer (score 0):

If the apparatus existed before with all the structure, you can't patent the apparatus for a different even novel use.

Comment: But you *can* patent the new method of use.